# CellEditEnding not getting new value first WPF programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

i am changing the value of a column cell, but whenever i hit enter, it display the old value. what can i do to make it give me the new value? Here's my code

```
private void DataGrid1_CellEditEnding_1(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    // Now you have the cell you are dealing with, so you can do what ever you want from here
    var currentRowIndex = DataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(DataGrid1.CurrentItem);
    int i = DataGrid1.SelectedIndex;
    DATA[currentRowIndex].TotalPrice1 = DATA[currentRowIndex].Quantity * DATA[currentRowIndex].ItemPrice;
    MessageBox.Show(DATA[currentRowIndex].TotalPrice1.ToString());
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = null;
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = DATA;
}
```

and heres my xaml

```
<DataGrid RowEditEnding="DataGrid1_RowEditEnding_1" CellEditEnding="DataGrid1_CellEditEnding_1" TargetUpdated="DataGrid1_TargetUpdated" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" EnableRowVirtualization="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="DataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding DATA,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, IsAsync=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10,10,10,10" PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid1_PreviewKeyDown" SourceUpdated="DataGrid1_SourceUpdated" TextInput="DataGrid1_TextInput" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Name" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=ItemName}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Price" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=ItemPrice}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="QuantityColumn" Header="Quantity" IsReadOnly="False"  Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Total Price" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=TotalPrice1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Why don't you just put that math in the getter of viewmodel property `TotalPrice1` and let binding do its job?

Comment: Well I can't seem to figure that out also.